# Find Out the content of the pdf is indexed or not?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

> How can i find-out whether the content of a file is indexed or not in
>   alfresco?
>
> I am using alfresco-5.0.d.

Answer (score 2):

You can hit the Solr web app directly. First, figure out what your node's sys:node-dbid is. You can get that from the node browser in the admin console.

Suppose it is 6834, for example. You can then go to:

https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/select?q=DBID:6834&wt=json

Which will return:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
     "params":{
        "q":"DBID:6834","wt":"json"
      }
  },
  "response":{
    "numFound":1,
    "start":0,"docs":[{
      "id":"_DEFAULT_!800000000000000b!8000000000001ab2",
      "_version_":0,
      "DBID":6834
    }]
  }
}
```

Assuming the node has been indexed. If it has not been indexed, numFound will be 0.

Doing this assumes you have the client certificate Solr and Alfresco are using to identify each other added to your browser.